# Tornado websocket async background task

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I try to create a tornado websocket, which is in the background. 
to handle events of input from a another device.

Usecase: Control the raspberry pi with a websocket connection from android app.

i am able to create a connection with the following implemtation:

main.py:

```
import sys

from sys import stdin
from websocket import connection


def main(args):
    print "start application"
    port = 7004
    if args[0] != port:
        port = args[0]

    connection.WebSocketConnection(port)
    core()


def core():
    run = True

    while run:
        userinput = stdin.readline()
        print userinput

        if userinput == 'quit':
            print "quit app"
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

connection handler:

```
import tornado.web
import message.MessageHandler

from message.messageConstructor import MessageConstructor
from tornado.web import asynchronous


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.send(message.MessageHandler.serialize(MessageConstructor('Engine1', '100')))

    def on_message(self, rawMessage):
        print rawMessage
        obj = message.MessageHandler.deserialize(rawMessage)
        print(obj.target)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def send(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)
```

connection:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import socket

from websocket import connectionHandler


class WebSocketConnection():
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.socketHandler = connectionHandler.WebSocketHandler

        application = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/', self.socketHandler),
        ])

        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(7004)
        myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        print '*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

    def send(self, message):
        self.socketHandler.send(message)
```

in the main.py file is function after the websocket creation and this function is never called. I guess it's a problem with the async chain of tornado.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out a way to do that, but i am not sure if this is the right way. Anyway in this set up it works:

main.py:

```
import sys

from sys import stdin
from websocket import connection
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


def main(args):
    print "start application"
    port = 7004
    if args[0] != port:
        port = args[0]

    connection.WebSocketConnection(port)
    core()

    IOLoop.instance().start()


def core():
    run = True

    while run:
        userinput = stdin.readline()
        print userinput

        if userinput == 'quit':
            print "quit app"
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

connection.py:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import socket

from websocket import connectionHandler


class WebSocketConnection():
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.socketHandler = connectionHandler.WebSocketHandler

        application = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/', self.socketHandler),
        ])

        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(7004)
        myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        print '*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP

    def send(self, message):
        self.socketHandler.send(message)
```

as you can see i start the loop just in the main file after calling the core function. In this way it works.

but as i said before i am not sure if this i really correct.